# BPMN process variable

Tags: java, jbpm, business-process-management, bpmn

I'm using JPBM to design a process flow, with BPMN2. I want to instantiate a class object in a Script Task, for example:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();    
Person p = new Person("moi");    
params.put("person", p);    
ksession.startProcess("com.sample.bpmn.hello", params);
```

When I go into BPMN and create the process variable, so I can access it inside the script task, I get the following error: "Person cannot be resolved to a type"

How can I access that object through BPMN then? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out. When creating the process variable, you have to define it as `Object` and provide the package path in Class Name. Instead of just creating an object, for example, of type `Person`, I had to actually type `com.sample.Person`, where `com.sample` is the package name. All variable reading and altering (`get` and `set` methods) is done with `kcontext.getVariable("var")` and `kcontext.setVariable("var", newValue)`.

Hope this helps anyone :)

Answer (score 2):

To resolve that issue, import the `Person` class in the `Process`. For that open the properties of the process, there you can find `imports` property.

So you can import that `Person` class by adding imports. You have to specify the fully qualified name in class attribute.